# C# Listview diffrent colors rows and columns

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I tryed to add different colors rows and columns on listview.

[I want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNOaJ.png)

[it is the first listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9CEJ.png)

Firstly i used these codes

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
   item.BackColor = item.Index % 2 == 0 ? Color.FromArgb(70, 70, 70) : Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 61);
}
```

[Then the listview shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EouGa.png)

And then i tryed these codes:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
   item.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(18, 64, 100);
   item.SubItems[9].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(105, 16, 38);
   item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
}
```

[Ande last listview shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A7Np.png)

Whats wrong?

thank you.

Comment: Which UI technology or framework are you using?

Comment: Obviously you need to combine the code ie set Backcolors depending on item index.

Comment: @ewerspej i used windows forms.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a DataGridView instead? Alternating Row colors is a standard property, you just specify the two colors. Cell level color definition, based on states / criteria, is handled by the `CellFormatting` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with this codes.

```
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
            {
                //Disable item styles for sub items so we can apply column colors.
                item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

                //Create the main colors used for row formatting.
                Color a = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 61);
                Color b = Color.FromArgb(70, 70, 70);

                //Create the alternate colors used for column 2 and 9.
                Color alt2 = Color.FromArgb(18, 64, 100);
                Color alt9 = Color.FromArgb(105, 16, 38);

                //Apply colors to column 1
                if (item.Index % 2 == 0)
                {
                    item.BackColor = b;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.BackColor = a;
                }

                int i = 0;
                foreach (ListViewSubItem sub in item.SubItems)
                {
                    sub.Name = i.ToString();
                    i++;
                }

                foreach (ListViewSubItem sub in item.SubItems)
                {
                    if (sub.Name == "3")
                    {             //Apply column 2 color.
                        sub.BackColor = alt2;
                    }
                    else if (sub.Name == "11")
                    {      //Apply column 9 color.
                        sub.BackColor = alt9;
                    }
                    else if (item.Index % 2 == 0)
                    { //Apply alt row color.
                        sub.BackColor = b;
                    }
                    else
                    {                          //Apply main row color. This is the default.
                        sub.BackColor = a;
                    }
                }

                listView.Sort();
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you apply alternating row colors, you only apply that to column 1 (aka. `item`). When you apply the column[2 and 9] formatting, you turn off `UseItemStyleForSubItems`, so only the first column now carries the alternating row colors. You have to combine the alternating row and column formating code into one code block like so:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
    //Disable item styles for sub items so we can apply column colors.
    item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

    //Create the main colors used for row formatting.
    Color a = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 61);
    Color b = Color.FromArgb(70, 70, 70);

    //Create the alternate colors used for column 2 and 9.
    Color alt2 = Color.FromArgb(18, 64, 100);
    Color alt9 = Color.FromArgb(105, 16, 38);

    //Apply colors to column 1
    if (item.Index % 2 == 0) {
        item.BackColor = b;
    } else {
        item.BackColor = a;
    }
    
    //Loop through the sub items and apply colors.
    foreach(ListViewSubItem sub in item.SubItems) {
        if (sub.Index == 2) {             //Apply column 2 color.
            sub.BackColor = alt2;
        } else if (sub.Index == 9) {      //Apply column 9 color.
            sub.BackColor = alt9;         
        } else if (item.Index % 2 == 0) { //Apply alt row color.
            sub.BackColor = b;            
        } else {                          //Apply main row color. This is the default.
            sub.BackColor = a;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. for your help. i get a error "sub.Index == 2". So i gave a names for the subitems.